# asio streambuf mutable buffer types - how to use prepare()

Tags: asio

Using standalone asio, I implemented a server with read_some.  My server loop accumulates all received data from the socket.  The stripped-down code below does NOT work properly, but I can fix it by moving the inbuf.prepare() statement into the loop.

```
asio::streambuf inbuf;
asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type inbufs = inbuf.prepare(4096);
while( connected )
{
    asio::error_code ec;
    size_t bytes_read = Socket().read_some(inbufs,ec);
    inbuf.commit(bytes_read);
    std::string s = std::string(asio::buffers_begin(inbufs),
            asio::buffers_begin(inbufs) + inbuf.size());
    inbuf.consume(bytes_read);
}
```

When prepare() is outside of the loop and the total bytes read since the connection was established crosses over the 4096 boundary, string s will only have the data up to that boundary.  In other words, s will be shorter than bytes_read.  I speculated that if I want to keep prepare() outside of the loop, I would need a consumption loop like the following, but this didn't work either.

```
asio::streambuf inbuf;
asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type inbufs = inbuf.prepare(4096);
while( connected )
{
    asio::error_code ec;
    size_t bytes_read = Socket().read_some(inbufs,ec);
    while(bytes_read > 0)
    {
        inbuf.commit(bytes_read);
        std::string s = std::string(asio::buffers_begin(inbufs),
            asio::buffers_begin(inbufs) + inbuf.size());
        inbuf.consume(inbuf.size());
        bytes_read -= s.size();
    }
}
```

Can anyone clarify the role of prepare(), and why it needs to be called repeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

`streambuf` is implemented as a `std::vector<char>` with a custom allocator. `prepare` simply allocates requested amount of memory. It doesn't need to be called more than once.

In order to preserve all received data you simply move the accumulator outside the main loop:

```
std::string accumulated_data;
while (connected) {
  ...
  accumulated_data.append(
      boost::asio::buffers_begin(inbufs),
      boost::asio::buffers_begin(inbufs) + bytes_read);
  ...
}
```

Warning: This may become very inefficient depending on the frequency and the total number of "appends" due to memory allocations and moves/copies. But since I have no clue what you want to do with the data, it's the best I can come up with.

Comment: In my case, I can estimate the size of the total data expected after the first chunk of it is read, so I can call accumulated_data.reserve() to avoid frequency memory reallocations.

Answer (score 0):

Asio::buffer is Simply a container. 
For more Detailed Information, Visit [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html)!

When asio::buffer is invoked, OS and Complier does not understand how much memory should be allocated to it. so buffer.prepare(/* Memory Size */) is called as member function to provide that space.

It is always recommended that one should allocated definite size of memory  to buffer, if don't received or transmitted data might get garbled.